# Calculating AUC Leave-One-Out cross validation in mlR?

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, auc, mlr

This is a quick question, just to make sure I'm not doing this the dumb way. I want to use `auc` as my measure in mlr, and I'm also using LOO due to the small sample size. Of course, in the LOO cross validation scheme the test sample is always only one instance, so `auc` can't be calculated. We can, of course, calculate it afterwards, looking at the predictions, the problem happens when we want to use it as the measure in the inner loop of nested crossvalidation. Something like this (you must define your own `binaryTask`):

```r
require(mlr)    
#for example purposes we will decide which one is better, vanilla LDA or
#vanilla SVM, in the task specified below
bls = list(makeLearner("classif.lda"),makeLearner("classif.svm"))
#modelMultiplexer allows us to search whole parameter spaces between models
#as if the models themselves were parameters
lrn = makeModelMultiplexer(bls)
#to calculate AUC we need some continuous output, so we set 
#predictType to probabilities
lrn = setPredictType(lrn, "prob")
lrn = setId(lrn, "Model Multiplexer")
#here we could pass the parameters to be tested to both SVM and LDA,
#let's not pass anything so we test the vanilla classifiers instead
ps = makeModelMultiplexerParamSet(lrn)
#finally, the resample strategy, Leave-One-Out ("LOO") in our case
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("LOO")
#parameter space search strategy, in our case we only have one parameter:
#the model. So, a simple grid search will do the trick
ctrl = makeTuneControlGrid()
#The inner CV loop where we choose the best model in the validation data
tune = makeTuneWrapper(lrn, rdesc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl, measure = auc, show.info = FALSE) 
#The outer CV loop where we obtain the performace of the selected model 
#in the test data. mlR is a great interface, we could have passed a list 
#of classifiers and tasks here instead and do it all in one go 
#(beware your memory limitation!)
res = benchmark(tune, binaryTask, rdesc, measure = auc)
```

You simply can't use `auc` like that, in both loops. How could we make `mlr` evaluate the measure over all the test samples instead of an unique resample each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different resampling strategy for the inner loop and then use `auc`:

```
library(mlr)    

ps = makeParamSet(
  makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "cp", default = 0.01, lower = 0, upper = 1)
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10)
inner = makeResampleDesc("Subsample")
lrn = makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
tune = makeTuneWrapper(lrn, resampling = inner, par.set = ps, control = ctrl, measure = auc)

outer = makeResampleDesc("LOO")
r = resample(tune, bc.task, resampling = outer, extract = getTuneResult, measure = auc)
```

You can also just take a resample result and compute an arbitrary performance measure on it, e.g. `performance(r$pred, auc)`.

Comment: Every other resampling strategy would allow me to calculate `auc`, surely, but I want to use `LOO` based on my datasets. But if no other answers come I'm open to jumping to Monte-Carlo CV. Thanks!

Comment: Ok then I'm not sure what you're asking. You can't use `auc` with LOOCV, so you'll have to use something else :)

Comment: I want to calculate the `auc` over the whole test sample, that is, every iteration of LOOCV, not in each sample alone, which is obviously not possible. That seems doable to me, but I'm not sure `mlR` would allow that.

Comment: That doesn't make sense -- you'd get the same number every time. It would be the same as doing it for the outer CV.

Comment: You would get only one number, just like you get only one accuracy `acc` estimate when doing `LOO`. Can't see the difference, really.

Comment: I guess I see your point, but as I've said this would be the same as doing it for the outer CV, no?

Comment: I want to optimize `auc` in the model selection (inner CV), so I need to evaluate it there, mostly because the threshold might be not optimal (if I evaluate `acc`) or the probabilities could be really uncalibrated (if I evaluate `brier`).

Comment: Hmm, so where are you setting a threshold? Note that mlr has `tuneThreshold()` for this purpose.

Comment: I could do that, but I want to evaluate `auc`, both in the inner and in the outer loops, and I would prefer to make it automatically.

Comment: Well as you say yourself, you can't compute `auc` on a single instance, so I guess the answer to your question is "you can't".

Comment: I don't want to measure `auc` on a single stance, I want to evaluate it on all the resampled test instances.

Comment: I realise that, but when you use LOOCV all test instances are just one. If you evaluate it on more, you're mixing train and test set.

Comment: I want to evaluate it on all test stances at once, not mix it with the training set. I'm led to believe that's possible (http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12428/60613), and I'd like to know how to do it in mlR.

Comment: Well in principle you can just take a resample result and compute an arbitrary performance measure on it, e.g. `performance(r$pred, auc)`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey Lars, I accepted your answer, but could you add the bit about calling `performance` in it? That's how I managed to do it (`auc` was the closed example in mlr, I was actually testing Gini for regression), and I'm currently writing an accessor function to make this easier. Thanks!